# Are the subsets $G^{+}$ and $G^{-}$ connected in $\mathbb{R^{2}}\setminus G$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

let $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and G its graph in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. We define $G^{-}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^{2}} : y<f(x) \}$ and $G^{+}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^{2}} : y>f(x)\}$, then we know that $G=G^{-}\bigcup G^{+}$ and that $G^{-}$ and $G^{+}$ are non empty disjoint open sets in $\mathbb{R^{2}}\setminus G$. Now all I need in order to show that the onely conneceted components of $\mathbb{R^{2}}\setminus G$ are $G^{-}$ and $G^{+}$ is to show that they are connected. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instructive to write $G$ as the image of a continuous function. Namely,

$$G = g_0(\mathbb{R});\,\, g_{0}(x) = (x, f(x))$$

Consider extending to $g_{c}(x) = (x, f(x)+c)$. Then $g$ is a continuous bijection $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly $G^{+}= g(\mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty))$ and ditto for $G^{-}$. They are connected sets, so their images under $g$ are connected too.

Comment: sorry, but what is $g$ ?

Comment: $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ takes $(x, c)$ to $(x, f(x)+c)$.

Comment: I think it should be $f(x)-c$ or $c-f(x)$?

Comment: @AbdellatifOuhaddou Are you sure? Don't you think $(x, f(x)-1)$ belongs to $G^{-}$ and not $G^{+}$?

Comment: Imagine a typical graph $G$. The idea behind $g$ is translating that graph up to get $G^{+}$ and down to get $G^{-}$.

Comment: So it should be $c-f(x)$, right ?

Comment: ... no? Why do you think so?

Comment: Because with $c-f(x)$ we gonna have $g(\mathbb{R}\times ]0,inf[)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}} : y-f(x)>0\}=G^{+}$ and $g(\mathbb{R}\times ]-inf,0[)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}} : y-f(x)<0\}=G^{-}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132585/discussion-between-preferred-anon-and-abdellatif-ouhaddou).